# How do I make this method return false when the word doesn't start with "qu"?

Tags: java, string, substring

My method should return `false` if the `String word` argument does not begin with "qu". I don't know how to make it work with a string longer than a single letter.

It currently gives me an error message : `incomparable types: boolean and int`

```
public boolean isQU( String word )
{
    String QU = "qu";        
    String letters = word.substring ( 0,2 );

    return ( ( QU ).equals( letters ) != -1 );
 }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `equals` will return `true` or `false`. Not a number you could compare to `-1`.

Comment: `return (QU.equals( letters ));` ?

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to use [`String.startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) (and check for `null`) like

```
public static boolean isQU(String word) {
    String QU = "qu";
    return word != null && word.startsWith(QU);
}
```

**or** first check for `null` and at least two characters like

```
if (word != null && word.length() > 1) {
    return word.substring(0, 2).equals(QU);
}
return false;
```

Comment: That second option needs to check the length of `word` first or it might error out. Depending on your on philosophy with regards to `null`, you may also want to `null`-check.

Answer (score 1):

First, the name you gave to the method is wrong. You are not testing if it is QU, you are testing if it starts with QU.

Anyway, a String in Java already has a method to check if it starts with something. It is called `starsWith` --what a surprise, huh?--. You use it like `word.startsWith("qu")`. It returns a boolean, as you would guess.

Answer (score 0):

The error "incomparable types: boolean and int" refers to this line:

```
return ( ( QU ).equals( letters ) != -1 );
```

... because equals returns always a boolean. So, you can't apply the operator `!=` to compare a boolean (`equals`) against an int (`-1`).

The immediate solution to your problem would be removing the comapration and let this line like this:

```
return ( ( QU ).equals( letters ));
```

This said, you can save yourself the trouble of implementing the `isQU` method, and delegate instead on the `String.startsWith` method:

```
return word.startsWith("qu");
```

It is safer than your initial solution, because yours would fail for strings shorter than two characters (You are not validating if the `substring(0,2)` can be safely called).